# ESP32-S3 with Coded PHY using Arduino

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-esp32, espressif-idf

I am using a M5AtomS3, which is a variant of the ESP32 using BLE 5. I would like to use the CODED_PHY function to extend the range of my project and develop in Arduino.

Based on [this](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/BLE/examples/BLE5_extended_scan/BLE5_extended_scan.ino) example I need to set CONFIG_BT_BLE_50_FEATURES_SUPPORTED which is supposed to be in the sdkconfig file. However it appears that I have to recompile Espressif libraries.

Is there an easier way of activating this feature or prebuilt libraries that do this?

Why would this feature not be enabled by default, given that the S3 is meant for BLE 5.

Answer (score 0):

Okay do after a week of messing around I found this library that does exactly what I was looking for.

https://github.com/h2zero/NimBLE-Arduino

The code already supports Bluetooth 5 and extended PHY can be set using nimconfig.h.

If you are using an RF%2 board with the ESP32 then you will need to install the n-ablecore  - https://github.com/h2zero/n-able-Arduino